# Visual Basic Syntax error. in page directive

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax-error

I have encountered the "BC30035 Visual Basic Syntax error." and it's shown to be in the page directive and can't see where the error comes from.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoginPacient.aspx.cs" Inherits="Proiect.LoginPacient" %>
```

and this is the code behind that I'm trying to use.

```
namespace Proiect
{
    public partial class LoginPacient
    {
        protected void Page_Load1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!((Page)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler).IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Proiect BD Connection String"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string checkPacient = "select count(*) from Pacienti where ID_Pacient='" + userID.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(checkPacient, conn);
                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

                if (temp == 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("Nu sunteti in baza de date. Va rugam sa va faceti cont");
                }

                conn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to Visual Studio, yet not new to programming, but can't see where the error comes from.

[image: solution explorer]

Comment: Are you trying to use c# in a VB.Net project?

Comment: You should never execute SQL with direct input from the user. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider moving to parametrized queries when you get more used to programming.

Comment: @Crowcoder it's a web form so I guess so

Comment: @bradbury9 thank you! it's just a school project i'm trying to figure out

Comment: could you show a screenshot of your solution explorer?

Comment: maybe you copy-pasted a vb.net web.config into a c# project? Check competent_tech's answer

Answer (score 3):

The most likely issue is that the compiler directive in your project's web.config file references VB instead of C#.

To resolve the issue, open your web.config and look for the `<compiler` directive.

When you find it, change

```
extension = ".vb"
```

to

```
extension = ".cs"
```

and

```
type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider
```

to

```
type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
```